# How to enable applications to send email from google container engine

Tags: email, smtp, google-cloud-platform

I am using a third party app in google container engine. It expects SMTP to be configured on default port(25) of localhost.

Since I cannot configure SMTP URL for the application and google cloud doesn't allow usage of SMTP ports, is there any way by which I can send emails from GKE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Kubernetes, you can send mails by adding a sidekick [Emailrelay](http://emailrelay.sourceforge.net/) container to your pod.

Emailrelay can run as-a-proxy. It listens on port 25 of localhost and forwards mails to an external SMTP server. It also supports authentication with outbound server and STARTTLS. Sample command will be like

```
emailrelay --no-daemon --as-proxy external.smtp.server:<PORT> --client-tls --client-auth /path/to/smtp/auth
```

Credentials file needs to be in format

```
LOGIN client username password
```

where, 'username' and 'password' should to be xtext encoded.

To overcome google cloud limitations, external server needs to accept SMTP requests on custom port.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the last part of your answer, "To overcome google cloud limitations, external server needs to accept SMTP requests on custom port.". Could you elaborate your answer a bit? In particular, I don't really see what external server means. Thanks

Comment: Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. So to connect via SMTP, your email service provider should listen to SMTP connection on a non-standard port

Comment: according to this only port 25 is blocked: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/